# Android Emulator vs phone opengl inconsistensies

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm having a problem where my application looks right on my emulator, but on my phone it only displays a fragment of my scene.

Images [here](https://sites.google.com/site/chrsin/stack) (The emulator is the one on the right.

My renderer code is seen here. (This class is abstract but all the implementing class is doing is draw the polygons)

```
public abstract class AbstractRenderer implements Renderer {
float x = 0.5f;
float y = 1f;
float z = 3;

boolean displayCoordinateSystem = true;

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    gl.glClearColor(.5f, .5f, .5f, 1);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    float ratio = (float) w / h;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 0, 10);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, x, y, z, 0f, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    if(displayCoordinateSystem) {
        drawCoordinateSystem(gl);
    }

    draw(gl);

//      gl.glFlush();
}

private void drawCoordinateSystem(GL10 gl) {
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(6*3*4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer vertices = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(6*2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    ShortBuffer indexes = ibb.asShortBuffer();

    final float coordLength = 27f;

    //add point (-1, 0, 0)
    vertices.put(-coordLength);
    vertices.put(0);
    vertices.put(0);

    //add point (1, 0, 0)
    vertices.put(coordLength);
    vertices.put(0);
    vertices.put(0);

    //add point (0, -1, 0)
    vertices.put(0);
    vertices.put(-coordLength);
    vertices.put(0);

    //add point (0, 1, 0)
    vertices.put(0);
    vertices.put(coordLength);
    vertices.put(0);

    //add point (0, 0, -1)
    vertices.put(0);
    vertices.put(0);
    vertices.put(-coordLength);

    //add point (0, 0, 1)
    vertices.put(0);
    vertices.put(0);
    vertices.put(coordLength);

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        indexes.put((short)i);
    }

    vertices.position(0);
    indexes.position(0);

    gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 0, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES, 2, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexes);

    indexes.position(2);
    gl.glColor4f(0, 1, 0, 0.5f);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES, 2, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexes);

    indexes.position(4);
    gl.glColor4f(0, 0, 1, 0.5f);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES, 2, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexes);
}

protected abstract void draw(GL10 gl);
}
```

My guess is that i'm not setting some value that is set by default by the emulator implementation. Only thing is i have no clue as to what that thing might be.

Hoping to hear from you dudes and dudettes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a depth buffer problem: From the "notes" section in the man page of [glFrustum](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/):

> near must never be set to 0.

You should calculate the near value to be as far from the camera as possible, and the far to be as close as possible, while still encompassing the things you want to draw.

Comment: Also, looks like your vertices are positioned 27 units away from the camera and your far distance is only 10 units. Good starting point would be gl.glFrustumf(...., 0.1f, 100.0f); and then you can tweak the values as ryanm suggested.

Comment: @Gilead I'm not so concerned with the vertices not showing at full length atm (They are going out before releasing the app anyways.). You did however supply a usefull way of tweaking for the right values for frustrum. Thx alot for your input!